# Why AWK uses my arguments as input file

Tags: linux, awk

I'm writing an awk script to let it parse something for me. For the purpose of convenience, I want the awk script to be executable in linux. Here are my codes:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 
BEGIN {
        FILENAME=ARGV[1]
        sub_name=ARGV[2]
        run=ARGV[3]
        count=0           
}

{ 
        if ($4 == "ARGV[2]" && $8 == ARGV[3])
        {
              print $15
              count=count+1
        }
}

END {
      print count
}
```

When I issue my awk script in linux such as:

> ./my_script 001.log type1 2

awk will say:

> awk: ./awk_script:23: fatal: cannot open file `type1' for reading (No such
>   file or directory)

I just want to let argument "type1" as a variable in my script, not a input file for parsing. How can I don't let awk treat it as an imput file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a shebang to execute the awk script as it just complicates things:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v sub_name="$2" -v run="$3" '
{ 
        if ($4 == sub_name && $8 == run)
        {
              print $15
              count=count+1
        }
}

END {
      print count
}
' "$1"
```

Note that your script could be cleaned up a bit:

```
/usr/bin/awk -v sub_name="$2" -v run="$3" '
($4 == sub_name) && ($8 == run) {
    print $15
    count++
}
END { print count+0 }
' "$1"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I think this solution is just like input a command line instruction to execute awk. What's the difference of using a script with shebang?

Comment: As you experienced, with a shebang you can't separate the shell arguments into awk variables and file names.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the non-file options from ARGV:

```
delete ARGV[2]
delete ARGV[3]
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way for me to run my script. Thank you @choroba

Comment: @JamieChou to be clear, this solution adds values to ARGV and then deletes them vs just not adding them to ARGV in the first place if you simply don't use a shebang.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use them as variables then you have to use the -v argument. The way you are trying to do it , suggests that the second argument is an input/output file

Comment: Do you mean I need to put my input in the first line of my script? I got an error message from awk if I just only change the first line from -f to -v. It seems to me that -v works when appending the variable with the first line. Could you provide more info on using -v? Thanks.

Comment: It seems this solution is similar to @Morton's solution. Thanks.